# Codename One online building error by terminal

Tags: maven, codenameone

I'm trying to use my CN1 account to compile online my project whit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS terminal command:

***$ mvn cn1:build -Dcodename1.platform=android -Dcodename1.buildTarget=android-device***

but I got this long error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for bo.conectica.carry:carry-common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.codenameone:codenameone-buildclient:jar refers to a non-existing file /home/synapsido/.codenameone/CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar @ bo.conectica.carry:carry:1.0-SNAPSHOT, /home/synapsido/Documentos/carry/pom.xml, line 293, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for bo.conectica.carry:carry-android:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.codenameone:codenameone-buildclient:jar refers to a non-existing file /home/synapsido/.codenameone/CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar @ bo.conectica.carry:carry:1.0-SNAPSHOT, /home/synapsido/Documentos/carry/pom.xml, line 293, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for bo.conectica.carry:carry:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.codenameone:codenameone-buildclient:jar refers to a non-existing file /home/synapsido/.codenameone/CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar @ line 293, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] carry                                                              [pom]
[INFO] carry-common                                                       [jar]
[INFO] carry-android                                                      [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< bo.conectica.carry:carry >----------------------
[INFO] Building carry 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                        [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.36:build (default-cli) > package @ carry >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.36:build (default-cli) < package @ carry <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.36:build (default-cli) @ carry ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for carry 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] carry .............................................. FAILURE [ 10.155 s]
[INFO] carry-common ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] carry-android ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.516 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-09T21:32:07-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.36:build (default-cli) on project carry: Execution default-cli of goal com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.36:build failed: Plugin com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.36 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.codenameone:codenameone-buildclient:jar:7.0.36 at specified path /home/synapsido/.codenameone/CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

maybe my **mvn** plugin version is deprecated? How to Update?

Comment: This is most important and first thing you should fix: `'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath'` because you are using `system` scoped dependencies...

Comment: @kmarbaise In this case the system scoped dependency is required.

Answer (score 1):

That particular target doesn't seem to trigger the download of that dependency.   If you run `mvn verify` first, or the "Run In Simulator" option in your IDE, it will cause these dependencies to be downloaded.

e.g.

```
mvn verify
```

then

```
mvn cn1:build -Dcodename1.platform=android -Dcodename1.buildTarget=android-device
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is an older version of the maven plugin (7.0.36) where the current is  `7.0.55`. Make sure to update the version and dependencies. You can use https://start.codenameone.com/ to generate a new reference.

The new version no longer depends on the file in that location.

Comment: Some tips for updating.  First try to simply change the cn1.version and cn1.plugin.version properties in the root pom.xml file to 7.0.55. 
If that isn't sufficient, it means that something in the project structure is actually out of date (e.g. includes explicit dependencies to old things).  In which case generating a new project is probably the best approach.

Comment: Change the version to 7.0.55 doesn't work, some other ideas? I use https://start.codenameone.com/ CN1 initializr, but still not working...

Comment: Can you update the logs with the new errors? Are they still pointing at the same missing file?
Did you update all the places (there's more than one) where the version is listed.

Comment: The error still the same: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.55:build (default-cli) on project carry: Execution default-cli of goal com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.55:build failed: Plugin com.codenameone:codenameone-maven-plugin:7.0.55 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.codenameone:codenameone-buildclient:jar:8.0 at specified path /home/usr/.codenameone/CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar

Comment: As a temporary workaround try adding the file there. You can download the file from https://www.codenameone.com/files/updates/CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar